# Cordova android emulator not running

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

when running `cordova run android` to the command panel. does nothing and writes the following:

```
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8
```

I'm sure I'm doing the system variables correctly.

I don't understand what the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says

> Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8

Your installed version is 11.0.2.

Download and install JDK 1.8 ( you can have multiple version installed ),
then make sure that your JAVA_HOME env variable points to the JDK 1.8